# BoltzTraP script works with which python version?

Tags: quantum-espresso, python, boltztrap

BoltzTraP code is giving errors in Quantum espresso of indentation and then Typerror: 'Float' object can not be interpreted as an integer.
What should I do to run this properly? What should I update or change? Maybe environment of the system is not set, But how to do that?

Comment: To avoid things getting too long here, I moved the discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60359703#60359703)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize the discussion from the comments/chat, the errors you are seeing are likely due trying to run BoltzTraP using Python3.9 when it is a Python2 program. I imagine some of these errors can be resolved simply by running this program with Python2.7.

However, neither Python2 nor BoltzTraP are actively developed. [BoltzTraP2](https://gitlab.com/sousaw/BoltzTraP2) is a more up to date Python module that works with Python3.5+. If you want to take advantage of or request potential bug fixes and new features, it would probably be best to switch to the newer version of this program.